# i want to put a variable in a aspx so when publishing it transform to actual date

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

I want to put a variable in a aspx so when publishing it transform to actual date...

I mean I want to change

Actual date: 23/12/10

for

Actual date: $date

and when it compiles it gets rendered

Comment: And do you want it to remain as it is? Will the value change every day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
Actual date: <%=Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")%>
```

See [this](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) handy list of `DateTime.ToString` formats.

Comment: excuse me , i dont explain it well, i dont want to do it in aspx, but in visual studio publishing, i mean: only when i click on publish site, like a msbuild action post publication...